# Why Copy Constructor not called?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    int size;
    double *arr;

public:
    A(int len):size(len)
    {
        cout<<"ctor called"<<endl;
        arr=new double[size];
    }
    A(const A &rhs)
    {
        cout<<"calling copy ctor"<<endl;
        size=rhs.size;
        arr=new double[size];
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout<<"calling dtor"<<endl;
        delete[] arr;
        arr=NULL;
        size=0;
    }
};
A createVector()
{
    cout<<"Creating object"<<endl;
    A a(10);
    cout<<"returning after creating object a"<<endl;
    return a;
}
void foo(A v)
{
    cout<<"Class A object rcvd"<<endl;
    //return v;
}
int main()
{
    A a=createVector();
    cout<<"a has been rcvd"<<endl;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

And I have the following output:

```
Creating object
ctor called
returning after creating object a
a has been rcvd
calling copy ctor
Class A object rcvd
calling dtor
calling dtor
```

I am having trouble with createVector() function. When I return a object by value,its copy constructor should be called but I am not seeing any output between the lines

```
returning after creating object a
a has been rcvd
```

Why copy constructor has not been called??
(when I pass the rcvd object as value to foo(),Copy Constructor gets called)

Comment: See [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: 'When I return a object by value,its copy constructor should be called', not necessarily true.

Comment: Also look up NRVO.

Comment: @songyuanyao The link says "Omits copy- and move- (since C++11)" ,so if I remove the -stdc++=11 flag,I should get the Copy Constructor called,right??
I checked,I am getting the same output.

Comment: It's RVO (return value optimization). It's meaning emplacement return value in variable where function calls

Comment: @aalisha You are misreading the documentation. Move only exists since C++11, that is what '(since C++11)' refers to. Copy elision has always existed.

Comment: @Treebeard I was more concerned with C++03's output for the above code.
I know in C++11 move semantics is present.